# Docker + MariaDB connection

Tags: docker, virtualbox, mariadb, sequelpro

Ive got a magent2 docker VM running - all working well. The only issue is I cant seem to figure out how to conenct to the DB via Sequel Pro...

Im using nginx/php7.0/mariaDB images with Dinghy/Docker/Virtualbox.

Pretty new to docker so if you could give me a hand connection to the DB via sequel pro will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you post a `docker port container_id` of your magent docker?

Comment: 3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8001 - im using the standard mariaDB image from the hub

Comment: check http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/connecting_to_a_mysql_server_on_a_remote_host

Comment: That doesnt help at all - I know how to connect to database servers using sequel pro. I just dont know how to using docker and its containers. I have the IP address of the MariaDB container but when using it in sequel pro it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the my.cnf bind-address values to bind to either a network adapter or all adapters via 0.0.0.0